# C++ convert UnicodeString into String

Tags: string, unicode, utf-8, c++builder, stdstring

Please help me somebody to convert unicodestring into string

This is how i am getting unicodestring

```
UnicodeString _str = OpenDialog1->FileName;
```

Or if it possible to write into file unicode string with ifstream or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: You did search before asking, didn't you?

Comment: Yes im searchin already 1 hour...

Comment: [UnicodeString::t_str Method](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__UnicodeString__t_str.html), yes you can also write into file too, just prefix your file with [`BOM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Stay away from the `t_str()` method.  It is dangerous to use, as it modifies the internal data of the `UnicodeString`, and has been removed in later versions of C++Builder anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your needs, assign the `UnicodeString` to an `AnsiString` or a `UTF8String`, and then write that to your file instead of the original `UnicodeString` itself:

```
UnicodeString _str = OpenDialog1->FileName; 
AnsiString _astr = _str;
```

Or:

```
UnicodeString _str = OpenDialog1->FileName; 
UTF8String _ustr = _str;
```

To pass an `AnsiString`/`UTF8String` to an STL function, you have to either:

1) use the `c_str()` method:

```
stream << _astr.c_str();
```

2) construct a temp `std::string`:

```
stream << std::string(_astr.c_str(), _astr.Length());
```

3) in the case of `AnsiString` only, specify the `VCL_IOSTREAM` define in your project to enable AnsiString's own `<<<` and `>>` operators:

```
stream << _astr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting your string to bytes would require some encoding. There are various libraries that do this, so it depends on the framework you are using.

As an alternative, you could use `wofstream` to write `wchar_t` characters to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string converted;
us.toUTF8String(converted);
```

us is (ICU) UnicodeString