# Convert unicode to string

Tags: c++, string, encoding, unicode

I need to retrieve string values from my database. However they come in the form of 
"\u00D0\u009A\u00D0\u00B5\u00D0\u00BD\u00D0\u00B9" . This happens when the strings entered are not in english. How to convert them to original strings.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: maybe this old answer can help you, I hope. 

[unicode to string c++][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291397/c-convert-unicodestring-into-string

Comment: (@ZaoTaoBao in comments you have to use `[text](url)` notation; the normal notation used in answers doesn't work)

Comment: Are those the actual strings (backslashes and all), or is that just because you're printing them out in some format that automatically escapes Unicode?

Comment: hi.. The database entry is "Зьцжб" but when i retrieve it the value is "Ð—ÑŒÑ†Ð¶Ð±" .

Comment: What encoding is that?

Comment: The database entry appears to be Cyrillic (which is a script, not an encoding), the retrieved value is in Latin (another script, not encoding). You can take an educated guess at the encoding problem because the incorrect string is twice as long, and the characters at even indexes are non-ASCII and from a small range (Ð appears 3 times, for instance). That is almost certain UTF-8 mis-interpreted as ISO-8859-x for some unknown x.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Java coding  , try as below.

```
// read Db value to stringValueFromDB  string , then convert as below

String sNewString  = stringValueFromDB.getBytes("UTF-8");
```